# tkinter multiple drowdown arguments

Tags: tkinter

So I am able to use a single variable ie. Voltage to print `True`

I am trying to use Voltage and Phase as arguments to print `True` but I am not having any luck

Here is my code so far:

```py
from tkinter import *

def edit_or_retrieve():
    Window = Tk()
    Window.title("Main Menu")
    Window.geometry("550x100")

    Box = StringVar(Window)
    Box.set("VOLTAGE")
    Voltage = ["120", "208", "240", "277", "480"] 
    Dropdown = OptionMenu(Window, Box, *Voltage, command=lambda x: function(x, Window))                                    
    Dropdown.pack(side = "left")

    Box = StringVar(Window)
    Box.set("PHASE")
    Phase = ["SINGLE PHASE", "THREE PHASE"] 
    Dropdown = OptionMenu(Window, Box, *Phase, command=lambda x: function(x, Window))                                    
    Dropdown.pack(side = "left")
    Window.mainloop()

def function(value, Window): 
    if value == '120':
        print(True)

edit_or_retrieve()
```

This will bring up a drop down box for Voltage and Phase, when I select Voltage I get `True`

Thanks for the help

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: I want to be able to do if value == "120" and abc == "SINGLE PHASE"

Comment: print "TRUE".  As of right now it only works with voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different tkinter variables (`StringVar`) for the two dropdowns and pass their values to `function()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

def edit_or_retrieve():
    Window = Tk()
    Window.title("Main Menu")
    Window.geometry("550x100")

    # tkinter variable for voltage
    voltage_var = StringVar(Window)
    voltage_var.set("VOLTAGE")
    Voltage = ["120", "208", "240", "277", "480"]
    voltage_dropdown = OptionMenu(Window, voltage_var, *Voltage,
                                  command=lambda x: function(x, phase_var.get(), Window))
    voltage_dropdown.pack(side = "left")

    # tkinter variable for phase
    phase_var = StringVar(Window)
    phase_var.set("PHASE")
    Phase = ["SINGLE PHASE", "THREE PHASE"]
    phase_dropdown = OptionMenu(Window, phase_var, *Phase,
                                command=lambda x: function(voltage_var.get(), x, Window))
    phase_dropdown.pack(side = "left")
    Window.mainloop()

def function(voltage, phrase, Window):
    if voltage == '120' and phrase == "SINGLE PHASE":
        print(True)

edit_or_retrieve()
```

Note that it is also better to use different variables for different instances of widgets.